# Extract only the values using XQueryCompiler in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xquery, saxon

I am using the following code to get some results from a XML file which is stored in a string. But the xquerycompiler demands that I enclose them into the `<result></result>`. Can I not enclose them and just get the output in a string? Here is my code:

```
Configuration saxonConfig = new Configuration();
Processor processor = new Processor(saxonConfig);                    

    XQueryCompiler xqueryCompiler = processor.newXQueryCompiler();
    XQueryExecutable xqueryExec = xqueryCompiler.compile("<result>{/book/chapter}</result>");
    XQueryEvaluator xqueryEval = xqueryExec.load();
    xqueryEval.setSource(new SAXSource(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmltext))));
    XdmDestination destination = new XdmDestination();
    xqueryEval.setDestination(destination);
    xqueryEval.run();

    System.out.println(destination.getXdmNode());
```

Comment: I can't see the difficulty, but I'm not sure I understand the requirement fully. What's the input, and what output do you want? What failure do you get if the query is reduced to `/book/chapter`?

Comment: This is the error I am getting: "Error on line 1 of *module with no systemId*: Only a single root node can be written to an XdmDestination". My program is generating multiple chapters, but since they are not enclosed in a root node, that is causing problem. Whats the solution?

Comment: If you don't want to wrap the chapters in an element node such as result, you could wrap them in a document node using the XQuery document-node{} constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not wrap the results in 'result', get the element back in a string, and then use simple substring functions to strip off the leading `<result>` and the trailing `</result>`?